# Explanation of subsetting

Tags: r

Can anyone explain what this line `t[exists,][1:6,]` is doing in the code below and how that subsetting works?

```
t<-trees
t[1,1]= NA
t[5,3]= NA
t[1:6,]
exists<-complete.cases(t)
exists
t[exists,][1:6,]
```

Comment: It looks like it's taking the first six rows of `t` after `t` has been subsetted to have the non-complete cases removed

Comment: By the way: you can achieve equivalent behavior with `head(t[exists, ], n = 6)`, or just `head(t[exists, ])` since 6 is the default anyway.

Comment: it's doing `(t[exists,])[1:6,]` basically. Btw both `t` and `exists` are quite prominent functions in R, I would recommend other variable names :).

Answer (score 1):

The `complete.cases` function will check the data frame and will return a vector  of `TRUE` and `FALSE` where a `TRUE` indicates a row with no missing data. The vector will be as long as there are rows in `t`.

The `t[exits,]` part will subset the data so that only rows where `exists` is true will be considered - the row that have missing data will be `FALSE` in `exists` and removed. The `[1:6,]` will only take the first 6 rows where there is no missing data.

Answer (score 1):

### Some background

In R, `[` is a function like any other. R parses `t[exists, ]` as

```
`[`(t, exists)  # don't forget the backticks!
```

Indeed you can always call `[` with the backtick-and-parentheses syntax, or even crazier use it in constructions like

```
as.data.frame(lapply(t[exists, ], `[`, 1:6, ))
```

which, believe it or not, is (almost) equivalent to `t[exists,][1:6,]`.

The same is true for functions like `[[`, `$`, and more exotic stuff like `names<-`, which is a special function to assign argument `value` to the `names` attribute of an object. We use functions like this all the time with syntax like

```
names(iris) <- tolower(names(iris))
```

without realizing that what we're really doing is

```
`names(iris)<-`(iris, tolower(names(iris))
```

And finally, you can type

```
?`[`
```

for documentation, or type

```
`[`
```

to return the definition, just like any other function.

### What `t[exists,][1:6,]` does

The simple answer is that R parses `t[exists,][1:6,]` as something like:

1. Get the value of `t`
2. From the result of step 1, get the rows that correspond to `TRUE` elements of `exists`.
3. From the result of step 2, get rows with row numbers in the vector `1:6`, i.e. rows 1 through 6

The more complicated answer is that this is handled by the parser as:

```
`[`(`[`(t, exists, ), 1:6, ) # yes, this has blank arguments
```

which a human can interpret as

```
temporary_variable_1 <- `[`(t, exists, )
temporary_variable_2 <- `[`(temporary_variable_1, 1:6, )
print(temporary_variable_2)  # implicitly, sending an object by itself to the console will `print` that object
```

Interestingly, because you typically can't pass blank arguments in R, certain constructions are impossible with the bracket function, like `eval(call("[", t, exists, ))` which will throw an `undefined columns selected` error.

Comment: a little correction, when doing `names(iris) <- tolower(names(iris))`, you're not doing `'names(iris)<-'(iris, tolower(names(iris))`, you're doing `iris <- 'names(iris)<-'(iris, tolower(names(iris))` (actually not quite, there's an intermediate step defining a `*tmp*` variable, which might pop up when using `subsitute` or doing funky things with environments)

Comment: `you typically can't pass blank arguments in R`, you'd have to be more precise, you're using the comment  "# yes, this has blank arguments" a few lines above

Comment: Try this out, this is the reason of this behavior : `test <- function(x,y) {print(missing(y));print(nargs())}; test(1); test(1,)`. From `?nargs`: 
`When used inside a function body, nargs returns the number of arguments supplied to that function, including positional arguments left blank`.  If you look at the code of `[.data.frame` you'll see it uses `nargs`.