# What is the difference between dataset[,'column'] and dataset$column in R?

Tags: r

If I want to list all rows of a column in a dataset in R, I am able to do it in these two ways:

```
> dataset[,'column'] 
> dataset$column
```

It appears that both give me the same result. What is the difference?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222286/select-a-data-frame-column-using-and-the-name-of-the-column-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In practice, not much, as long as `dataset` is a data frame. The main difference is that the `dataset[, "column"]` formulation accepts variable arguments, like `j <- "column"; dataset[, j]` while `dataset$j` would instead return the column named `j`, which is not what you want.

`dataset$column` is list syntax and `dataset[ , "column"]` is matrix syntax. Data frames are really lists, where each list element is a column and every element has the same length. This is why `length(dataset)` returns the number of columns. Because they are "rectangular," we are able to treat them like matrices, and R kindly allows us to use matrix syntax on data frames.

Note that, for lists, `list$item` and `list[["item"]]` are almost synonymous. Again, the biggest difference is that the latter form evaluates its argument, whereas the former does not. This is true even in the form `` `$`(list, item) ``, which is exactly equivalent to `list$item`. In Hadley Wickham's terminology, `$` uses "non-standard evaluation."

Also, as mentioned in the comments, `$` always uses partial name matching, `[[` does not by default (but has the option to use partial matching), and `[` does not allow it at all.

I [recently answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26305063/2954547) with some additional details that might interest you.

Comment: It's not the only difference. Don't forget that the `$` method allows for partial name matching. So, one could (but shouldn't) do `dataset$col` and get the values for `dataset$column`. That can cause issues for the unwary.

Comment: Actually I _did_ forget, what with tab completion and a healthy mistrust of partial matching.

Comment: `[[` supports partial matching, e.g.: `dat <- data.frame(variable1=1:3); dat[["v",exact=FALSE]]` The help file at `?Extract` even goes through this: _"‘x$name’ is equivalent to ‘x[["name", exact = FALSE]]’_

Comment: @thelatemail more things I didn't know. Edited

Comment: Ohhhh, that's what `exact` does in a list index?!?!  I never really took time to learn that but knew it was there. Woohoo for thelatemail!

Comment: So I just went back and read through the docs. Turns out that `[[` also has an argument `j`, so you can use matrix syntax with it as well. Now _I'm_ confused as to what the difference is.

Comment: @ssdecontrol - it's mainly that `[` allows multiple selections.

Comment: Just my opinion but I stopped using data$var as the partial name matching can lead to badness in coding and unexpected results.

Comment: @thelatemail of course. That's enough thinking for today.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'str' command to see the difference:

```
> mydf
  user_id Gender Age
1       1      F  13
2       2      M  17
3       3      F  13
4       4      F  12
5       5      F  14
6       6      M  16
> 
> str(mydf)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ user_id: int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ Gender : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 2 1 1 1 2
 $ Age    : int  13 17 13 12 14 16
> 
> str(mydf[1])
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ user_id: int  1 2 3 4 5 6
> 
> str(mydf[,1])
 int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> 
> str(mydf[,'user_id'])
 int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6

> str(mydf$user_id)
 int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> 
> str(mydf[[1]])
 int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6
> 
> str(mydf[['user_id']])
 int [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

mydf[1] is a data frame while mydf[,1] , mydf[,'user_id'], mydf$user_id, mydf[[1]], mydf[['user_id']] are vectors.

Comment: You can use `drop=FALSE` with a couple of those if you want to get a `data.frame` back.